# A Cousin's Code: Settle It!

Tags: knowledge, cipher

So I have a younger cousin who's been hanging out with a group of other teens recently.  Unfortunately, my cousin is at the stage where they don't want to talk about their friends to their parents, so my aunt is freaking out that the group's all into drugs, or gang wars, or drug-fueled gang wars.  *I* think they just sit around and play video games.  Whatever.

Anyway, my aunt rooted through my cousin's room and found this note from one of their friends (named Nester or something like that).  She's convinced that it's a map of houses the group is gonna rob or something.  I'm fairly sure it's a message of some sort, but my aunt won't stop fretting unless I can tell her what's going on and what the message says.

So, can you find the way to interpret this grid and save my cousin from a preemptive grounding?

[image]

For color-blind puzzlers...

> 45 27 313 111 are purple
> 33 22 44 11 are cyan
> 23 12 35 46 are yellow
> 34 42 17 210 are green
> 29 31 410 18 are orange
> 49 13 21 36 are pink
> 314 24 14 43 are blue
> 48 32 15 26 are red

Hints

> There's a good amount of extra space in the picture--that's on purpose.

> Every number is different for aesthetic purposes--there easily could have been repeated numbers.

> The source of the grid is hinted at a couple of times in the setup, one hint more obscure than the other.

> If I had made this puzzle before the end of June, the grid would look different, and had I made it last year, different still.

> El-Guest's picture is accurate and useful, but this picture might be more useful...[image]

Comment: +1 for being inclusive of colour-blind puzzlers.

Comment: @exal Regarding your second hint - rot13(qb lbh zrna gung gur ahzoref ner zrnavatyrff, be gung tvira gur pubvpr orgjrra gjb ahzoref gung lbh pbhyq unir cvpxrq gung svg va, lbh pubfr gb cvpx barf gung jrer havdhr)?

Comment: @kristinalustig  The latter.  The numbers are not meaningless.

Comment: I think another hint is needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is

> The tournament is at eleven at my house

---

Explanation

> As [figured out my El-Guest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/101092/37714), the grid represents the character selection of the game [Smash Ultimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Smash_Bros._Ultimate)
>  
>  [image]
>  
>  
>  If we treat each digit of a number as instructions to extract a specific letter in the underlying character's name, we get the following grid:
>
>  [image]
>  (Note: e.g. 313 is treated as 3-13, not 3-1-3)
>  
>  
>  Whats interesting about the original grid with numbers is that every number in the same color group follows a pattern: One number starts with the digit 1, one with 2, one with 3, and one with 4. If we interpret that as the ordering of the letter pairs for each color, we get the following: 
>  Red: RT IH NE KT
>  Blue: HO LU KR MN
>  Yellow: DA AM WE NN
>  Green: DT II SS TA
>  Orange: BT CE CL GE
>  Cyan: VV EE NN AA
>  Pink: PT EM DY AH
>  Purple: BO AM RS KE
>  
> (Note: The ordering of the colors themselves are the order of colors which would be present on the bottom part of the character selection in the game if all 8 players selected a character)
>  
>  Furthermore, the fact that the first digit of each number denotes the ordering suggests that the first letter we extracted of a cell is actually not part of the ciphertext, so let's remove the first letter of each pair:
>  Red: T H E T
>  Blue: O U R N
>  Yellow: A M E N
>  Green: T I S A
>  Orange: T E L E
>  Cyan: V E N A
>  Pink: T M Y H
>  Purple: O M S E
>  
>  Which, if you read it left to right, top to bottom, spells out the message. (The last M seems to be a mistake from OPs part, purple's 27 should be 28 to spell out U)

Comment: Drat, I thought I had double-checked all my numbers.  Ah well, good job!

Answer (score 4):

**Partial Answer**
I’ve been looking at this awhile, so hopefully this can help somebody!

So I think this refers to

> The character selection screen from the game Smash Ultimate. Note that new characters were added on June 30 (Min Min), and a few were added between last year and now, meaning the shape of the grid would have changed. [image: Smash]

So, to decrypt this

> Let’s try taking the letters of each character going row by row, ie. KE from Donkey Kong, AM from Samus, etc.

Purple:

> KE AM RS BI

Cyan:

> NN EE AA LL

Yellow:

> AM DA WE IJ

Green:

> SS TA DT II

Orange:

> CE CL GE BT

Pink:

> AH PT EM DY

Blue:

> KR LU HO MN

Red:

> KT NE RT IH

And here we’re stuck, because I can’t see if this is the right path....